# Why Flags are replaced with statue on disney logo building?

Tags: credits, disney, beauty-and-the-beast-2017

In Beauty and the Beast (2017), During opening scenes, Disney Logo used to have flags on building but this movie showed differently with statue of some **winged man with spear in his hand** on top of the building.

[image]

Comment: Seems suggestive of the archangel [Michael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_(archangel)) slaying Satan in the form of a dragon.

Comment: Or St. George slaying the dragon. FWIW, that's an image that appears in two places at Epcot -- the Germany and Italy pavilions both have representations. There ISN'T one at the France pavilion, AFAICR, and they've set B&B in France, so that's odd.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because it is typical of a 1700 castle to have gargoyles or other statues instead of flags. The Disney castle in the movie is supposed to be the Princes actual castle.